# Unity Controller: Moving while jumping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

> Hi all, I'm currently trying to learn how Unity works (very new to everything coding/game building), and the different facets of game making. Right now I'm working on getting a movable character into my game- I did this successfully following a tutorial on YouTube, then tried another tutorial so I could get a sprint command.

> I was able to achieve this but I had an issue moving forward while I'm jumping, so when I jump while running, the character stops in place to jump.

> I have the code below and was hoping for some advice, thanks!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movementcontroller : MonoBehaviour
{
    //VARIABLES
    [SerializeField] private float moveSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private float walkSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private float runSpeed;

    private Vector3 moveDirection;
    private Vector3 velocity;

    [SerializeField] private bool isGrounded;
    [SerializeField] private float groundCheckDistance;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask groundMask;
    [SerializeField] private float gravity;

    [SerializeField] private float jumpHeight;


    //REFERENCES

    private CharacterController controller;

    private void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Move();
    }
     
    private void Move()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, groundCheckDistance, groundMask);

        if(isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }

        float moveZ = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        float moveX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        moveDirection = new Vector3(moveX, 0, moveZ);
        moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);

        if(isGrounded)
        {
            moveDirection *= moveSpeed;

            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                Jump();
            }
        }

        if(moveDirection != Vector3.zero && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                Walk();
            }
            else if(moveDirection != Vector3.zero && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                Run();
            }
            else if(moveDirection == Vector3.zero)
            {
                Idle();
            }

        controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    private void Idle()
    {

    }

    private void Walk()
    {
        moveSpeed = walkSpeed;
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        moveSpeed = runSpeed;
    }

    private void Jump()
    {
        velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2 * gravity);
    }

}
```

Comment: You seem to only multiply movedirection with movementspeed when you are grounded. Might have something to do with that.

Comment: please provide more details into your question. its hard to help you unless you talk about what are you making? what type of movement? first person or third person. And there is many easy way to make movement script. check Brackeys video on YouTube it will help you a lot   .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
moveDirection *= moveSpeed;        
if(isGrounded)
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        Jump();
    }
}
```

Instead of this:

```
    if(isGrounded)
    {
        moveDirection *= moveSpeed;

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Jump();
        }
    }
```

Your current version says, that moveDirection should only change if the player is grounded, which is not true when the player jumps.